# The text suddenly is too small to read in ctrl-F Navigation in Microsoft word (of Office 365)

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, microsoft-word-365

I unhibernated my Windows 10 laptop, my MS word doc was still open from last time, I pressed ctrl-F to find something, the "Navigation" pane and its text is too small to read.

Never had problem before.  Been using the laptop a long time.

How can I restore Nav pane text to normal size[image]?

[image]

Comment: Try to see under Settings -> System -> Display -> Scale & Layout if the percentage of "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" is the way you set it up. If not change it to the recommended value and check if the Navigation pane's font size goes to back to normal or not.

Comment: Also try holding Ctrl key while scrolling with the mouse wheel with the cursor over the desired pane. Some panes zoom in or out, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

If you close Word and restart is the size restored?

If not, try [opening Word in safe mode](https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72). To do this, you can hold the `Ctrl` key down when starting Word. Then when Word comes up, use `Ctrl+N` to put a document on screen. Try opening the document that has the headings. If that works, the problem likely is with an Add-In.

If not, try repairing your Office installation. You can find instructions [here](https://support.office.com/article/7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).